Matrix representation of linear transformation w.r.t a basis
Let $T\in L(\mathbb{C}^2)$ defined by $T(x,y)=(y,-x)$. Then $P_T(x)=x^2+1=(x-i)(x+i)$. Then $-i,i$ are eigenvalues of $T$ and $T$ is diagonalizable. Now, we try to find the corresponding eigenvectors:
$(y,-x)=i(x,y)\iff y=ix$ and $-x=iy\iff y=ix$. So, take $(x,y)=(1,i)$.
Similarly, $(y,-x)=-i(x,y)\iff y=-ix$ and $-x=-iy\iff y=-ix$. So, take $(x,y)=(1,-i)$.
Consider the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B=\{(1,i),(1,-i)\}$, this is $$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix} i & -i\\
-1 & -1
\end{pmatrix}.$$

I think everything is fine except the fact that my professor said that $$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix} i & 0\\
0 & -i
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So the question are: Who is right? my professor or me? I assume my professor. Also, in case my professor is right, how did he get the matrix $[T]_B$?

But in order for $[T]_B$ to be the way my professor said, it should hold that $[T(1,i)]_B=(i,0)^T$ and that $[T(1,-i)]_B=(0,-i)^T$. However, as you can see, I got different results for $[T(1,i)]_B, [T(1,-i)]_B$.

@user926356 Exactly, those are the coordinates of $T(1,i)$ and $T(1,-i)$ as linear combinations of the elements of $B$.

@Charlie4 If I was able to identify my mistake correctly, it was that I did not express $T(1,i),T(1,-i)$ as linear combinations of the elements of $B$. Correct?

@user926356 Yes. You expressed them as linear combinations of the standard basis vectors, which gets you the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ in the domain and the standard basis in the codomain, as Stéphane pointed out.

@StéphaneJaouen Thanks! I didn't even notice I had a typo in the decomposition of $P_T$

The matrix $[T]_B$ keeps track of the coordinates (with respect to the basis $B$) of where $T$ maps the elements of $B$.
Letting $e := (1,i)$ and $f := (1,-i)$ be our basis vectors, we have that $$T(e) = ie + 0f$$ and $$T(f) = 0e -if.$$ So the coordinates of $T(e)$ and $T(f)$ with respect to $B$ are $(i,0)$ and $(0, -i)$, which are the columns of the matrix that your professor wrote down.

Ok, done! Now I have that $T(1,i)=(i,-1)=i(1,i)+0(1,-i)$ and $T(1,-i)=(-i,-1)=0(1,i)+-i(1,-i)$

Let's remember what it is $\mathbb C^2$ $$\mathbb C^2=\mathbb C\times \mathbb C:=\{(z,t):z\in\mathbb C \text { and }t\in\mathbb C \}$$
It is better to use such notations so as not to confuse it with the classic uses of $x$ and $y$ as reals, since the pair of reals (x,y) usually denotes a single complex $$z=(x,y)\in \mathbb C$$
This is important because here we are dealing with a linear application $T$ of a vector $\mathbb C$- dimension $2$ vector space in itself define precisely as follows $$T:\mathbb C\times \mathbb C\to \mathbb C\times \mathbb C$$ $$(z,t)\mapsto (t,-z)$$
In this $\mathbb C$-vector space, we can use many bases:

the canonical basis $$\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$$Every element (z,t) of $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$ can be written $$(z,t)=z(1,0)+t(0,1)$$

the basis $\{e,f\}$ defined by @Charlie4 in his answer.



What OP wrote (in his OP, before correcting by himself in the comments) is the matrix of $T$ in two distinct bases $$Mat(T,\color{red}{\{e,f\}},\color{green}{\{(1,0),(0,1)\}})$$
This is not what was asked of him, and @Charlie4 corrected.

I see your point, it's important to remember that we make a choice of basis for the domain and codomain of $T$.
